# CoreBluetooth read/write data

Tags: ios, nsdata, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, lgbluetooth

I am working with iOS central to communicate with BLE peripheral device.

Using LGBluetooth framework https://github.com/DavidSahakyan/LGBluetooth

The method gets

```
        [LGUtils readDataFromCharactUUID:aCharactId
                              seriveUUID:aServiceId
                              peripheral:peripheral
                              completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Data : %s Error : %@", (char *)[data bytes], error);
                              }];
```

It outputs "1234567890"

I need to convert (char *) [data bytes] to NSInteger.
When I get it

```
         NSInteger dataInt = [data bytes];
```

I get 2013527536, but the value is 1234567890 on peripheral side

Comment: Above link doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like that:

```
NSInteger dataInt = atoi((const char*)[data bytes]);
```

Comment: I used atol((const char*)[data bytes])